Accessing a variable in Solidity
Suppose I have contract A and contract B. Contract A is of type contract B. I would like for B to have access to constants belonging to Contract A
Contract B {

//I want to access myAddr inside contract B

}

Contract A is B {

address public myAddr;

}


I tried address(this).myAddr() but it does not work. I am using solidity =0.5.16

You’re doing it inversely. In your case, contract A can access the non-private members   including state variables and internal methods of contract B, as contract A is derived/child contract and contract B is base/parent contract.
Here’s an example to illustrate accessing variables of the parent contract:
// Parent contract
contract Parent {
    uint public parentVariable;
    
    constructor(uint _value) {
        parentVariable = _value;
    }
}

// Derived contract
contract Derived is Parent {
    uint public derivedVariable;
    
    constructor(uint _value, uint _derivedValue) Parent(_value) {
        derivedVariable = _derivedValue;
    }
    
    function getSum() public view returns (uint) {
        // Accessing parentVariable from the parent contract
        return parentVariable + derivedVariable;
    }
}


In your case, you can access a public variable myAddr by creating an instance of contract A using its deployed contract address, like this:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract B {
    function getAddressFromContractA(address address_contractA) external view returns (address) {
        A a = A(address_contractA);  // creating instance of contract A
        return a.myAddr();           // accessing myAddr inside contract B
    }

    function setAddressOfContractA(address address_contractA, address _newAddress) external {
        A a = A(address_contractA);  // creating instance of contract A
        a.setAddress(_newAddress);   // setting myAddr inside contract B
    }
}

contract A is B {
    address public myAddr;

    function setAddress(address _address) external {
        myAddr = _address;
    }
}


Yeah but that's not what I need, I need to make it work in the case I stated

@qubitz, I've added that to my answer. Please check.

The problem is that B doesn't any idea about A's variables. In OOP one way to solve this is using interfaces (or abstract contracts)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


abstract contract B {
    function foo(address x) public {
        if (getMyAddr() != x) {
            setMyAddr(x);
        }
    }

    function getMyAddr() virtual internal view returns (address);
    function setMyAddr(address) virtual internal;
}

contract A is B {
    address public myAddr;

    function getMyAddr() override internal view returns (address) {
        return myAddr;
    }

    function setMyAddr(address a) override internal {
        myAddr = a;
    }
}

But you haven't won much, it almost the same as to define myAddr in contract B.

To ensure Contract B has access to myAddr from Contract A, it's important to correctly inherit Contract A into Contract B. Here's the proposed solution with that additional clarification:
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

// Proposed solution:
contract B {
    address public myAddr = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;
}

contract A is B {
    constructor() public {}

    function getMyAddr() public view returns (address) {
        return myAddr;
    }
}

// Make sure Contract A is properly inherited into Contract B for access to myAddr.
This way, Contract B can access myAddr defined in Contract A.

